# WIN 32 API - passing multiple Flags - Why the 'OR' and not 'AND'

Tags: winapi

When calling win32 API native functions, why do we pass multiple flags in an 'Or' rather than in an 'And' ?

for example: [SetWindowPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) at its last parameter accepts `UINT uFlags`

When you want to pass more than one value to it, for example, from VBA you declare it and call it:

```
SetWindowPos hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
```

my question is - why the 'or' in between the flags (`SWP_NOACTIVATE, SWP_SHOWWINDOW , etc ...`) and not an 'and' ?

Comment: Start by reading what these operators do. Without that knowledge you won't get far. These are bitwise operators.

Comment: because if you will be use *and* you got 0 as flag

Answer (score 1):

The 'OR' operator preserves the values of the combined flags.
if you are familiar with [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), take these two values for example:

```
0b0010
0b0001
```

if you evaluate these expressions using the AND operator.

```
    0010
AND 0001
    ----
    0000
```

you'll get `0b0000` representing none of the original flag values.
on the other hand, using the OR operator

```
    0010
OR  0001
    ----
    0011
```

will get you an expression representing the combined value of the flags.

Comment: How can I get back the previous  constituting flags if I know the answer after OR operation?

Comment: @Biswapriyo you can not. both `OR` and `AND` are destructive operations. you can only reverse `XOR` and `NOT`

Comment: Let say, `X or Y = Z` if I know Z and Y then can I get X?

Comment: Very late answer, but yes, `X or Y = Z`, then you can tell if Z contains X with `Z and X == X`